# std::thread arguments (value vs. const)

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

When I generate a new thread (`std::thread`) with a function the arguments of that function
are by value - not by reference.

So if I define that function with a reference argument (`int& nArg`)
my compiler (mingw 4.9.2) outputs an error (in compilian-suaeli something like
"missing copy constructor" I guess ;-)

But if I make that reference argument const (`const int& nArg`) it does not complain.

Can somebody explain please?

Comment: believe it or not, some are able to read and understand what you call "compilian-suaeli", so please include the full error message in the question. Btw also some can read code, so please add a [mcve]

Comment: I do not doubt it. With that term I meant that typical compiler messages that don't help much to find the cause.

Comment: You should be able to get your error output in English, e.g. by setting `LC_ALL=C` in the environment.

Comment: wewe ni suali? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass reference, you have to wrap it into [`std::reference_wrapper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper) thanks to [`std::ref`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref). Like:

```
#include <functional>
#include <thread>

void my_function(int&);

int main()
{
    int my_var = 0;
    std::thread t(&my_function, std::ref(my_var));

    // ...
    t.join();
}
```

Comment: Yes, thanks, I found out myself ;-) But I was wondering why it works with reference when I make the argument const.

Comment: Look at [thread](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread), *"The arguments to the thread function are moved or copied by value"*, so there are temporary, and cannot bind to non-**const** reference.

Comment: No complain of the compiler if I do void my_function (const int&); int my_var = 0; std::thread t(&my_function, my_var);

Comment: Because the temporary can bind to const reference.

Comment: Looks like that is the answer. Although I don't understand so far. I will have to think that over, read information. Thank you!

Comment: to pass rvalue reference you need to use const because the are temporary and don't hold memory in heap or stack. they are not supposed to be modified.

Answer (score 0):

`std::thread`'s arguments are used once.

In effect, it stores them in a `std::tuple<Ts...> tup`.  Then it does a `f( std::get<Is>(std::move(tup))...)`.

Passing `std::get` an rvalue `tuple` means that it is free to take the state from a value or rvalue reference field in the tuple.  Without the tuple being an rvalue, it instead gives a reference to it.

Unless you use `reference_wrapper` (ie, `std::ref`/`std::cref`), the values you pass to `std::thread` are stored *as values* in the `std::tuple`.  Which means the function you call is passed an rvalue to the value in the `std::tuple`.

rvalues can bind to `const&` but not to `&`.

Now, the `std::tuple` above is an implementation detail, an imagined implementation of `std::thread`.  The wording in the standard is more obtuse.

---

Why does the standard say this happens?  In general, you should not bind a `&` parameter to a value which will be immediately discarded.  The function thinks that it is modifying something that the caller can see; if the value will be immediately discarded, this is usually an error on the part of the caller.

`const&` parameters, on the other hand, do bind to values that will be immediately discarded, because we use them for efficiency purposes not just for reference purposes.

Or, roughly, because

```
const int& x = 7;
```

is legal

```
int& x = 7;
```

is not.  The first is a `const&` to a logically discarded object (it isn't due to reference lifetime extension, but it is logically a temporary).